# Efficient way of exporting a bunch of PDF's from a user?

Tags: php, pdf, cron, wkhtmltopdf

I need to give our users the ability to export a bunch of their PDF's (invoices).
The problem is, the PDF's are generated everytime a user opens them.

So I don't have them already stored in a filesystem.

So, my question is, what would be an efficient way of exporting a user's PDF's, when they want to?

For example, a user wants to export 100 invoices from the previous quarter.

I would then need to call a script that generates the PDF's and put them in a .zip file.

**But**, what if multiple users request a heavy export at the same time?

I was thinking of running a cronjob every 10 minutes or so, but that doesn't solve the possible heavyness of the script.

Do I need to run multiple cronjobs, so they can each handle a portion of the exports?

Or can I somehow create a really efficient script, and maybe separate all PDF's in several batches?

I'm using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org) to generate the PDF's.

So fortunately, it's pretty fast to render the PDF's.

Although it still depends on the content, of course.

On average, a single PDF takes about 3-5 seconds to render.

Any help or guidelines would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

---

Follow-up question: If I save every invoice into a filesystem, as soon as it's created or updated, I need to find a way to do this in the background, to avoid unnecessary waiting.

Queues would be my savior, right?

Comment: I'm currently developing a very similar setup. I'm very happy with using gearmand Job server - It's a really nice (distributed) Job Queue System to execute heavy processing in the Background. Also note that using a single Xvfb-Process for the whole batch instead of using `xfvb-run` may speed up the generation heavily. (It takes 0.09secs/Page and scales exactly with the number of CPU-Cores)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate the invoices the moment they are saved in the database and store the filesystem-URL with the database entry. If the user requests a package of invoices of a certain time period, collect the already generated PDFs into a zip-file and provide a download link.
Requirement is enough space for file storage on the server.

You can limit the invoice storing to one year. If an user requests older invoices they must be generated otf.

---

Follow-Up Answer:
Since you are in PHP-environment, i would suggest implementing some kind of invoiceChanged handler. If you call it (with parameter invoiceNr), the deprecated PDF-file gets deleted and a new one is generated according to the modified data. If it uses the same file-name, you do not even have to update the file-URL in your database.

Comment: The problem is, none of the current invoices are stored. So I would still need a script to render and store all of them, beforehand?

Comment: That would be a single-time task which surely would need some time, but does not sound too complicated. A simple script calling the wkhtmltopdf lib for every invoice; saving invoice to filesystem and link to db would do.

Comment: I would still need an efficient script to do that, since we are talking about 10k+ invoices, and rising fast. And if I have such a script, I could rather use that script with on-the-fly generating while exporting, too?

Comment: Correct, the single-task generation and the otf-generation would need two different implementations. I suggest, your best bet will be testing the performance of the single-task script by trying it  with 100 invoices. Due to it's linear complexity, you can easily estimate the tasks duration.

Comment: You're right, it's still the better solution to perform this single-time task first.
Could you please see my follow-up question edit, too?

Comment: Added my suggestion to my answer

Comment: Assuming your Invoice Data is stored in an MySQL-Database, Gearman Job server (see my comment to the question) offers you UDF Functions. If you set up an 'update'-Trigger for the database, the PDF could be generated completely asynchronous when the data get's changed (Of course, without blocking MySQL).